# Show UTC time according to user's timezone

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am having some date-time values coming from SharePoint. SharePoint stores all times in UTC format. So, when displaying to user, I am converting UTC time to local time zone using this code -

```
    internal static DateTime? ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime? utcTime)
    {
        if (utcTime.HasValue)
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime.Value, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Am I right in saying that this will return time according to timezone of the server hosting web application?
Currently our production server is based in UK and users are also based in UK. So, above code will work fine.

But going forward, production server and even users can be anywhere in the world. What shall I do to make it error free for future enhancement?
Do I need to use javascript to find current user's timezone, save that information in session and then use this information when showing any date-time value?

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend your last written point, it is the most logical thing to do to me. UTC works everywhere, you just need to adjust the display on the client machines.

Comment: Are the users authenticated ? If so, you could store their timezone when they register with your application and then use that to convert the time to the appropriate zone

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeZoneInfo` class can be used to manage your time zone needs.

Assuming you can on the client side obtain an string corresponding to the `Id` values used by `TimeZoneInfo` (which in turn are straight from the Windows registry, but are intended to match standardized English names for the time zones), then you can use [`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid(v=vs.110).aspx) to look up the correct object, and use e.g. the [`ConvertTimeFromUtc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc(v=vs.110).aspx) method to convert to local time for display.

I haven't used it, but there is also the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library to handle all your date/time management needs. A similar library for JavaScript is [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which could be useful if (as it seems) you have a JavaScript client and want to handle the local time in client-side code.

I'm unfamiliar with JavaScript, but I assume it has some built-in support for time zones, and of course there is at least one library to do so.

If it were me, I would try to handle *all* of the local time zone issues client-side. I.e. your server-side code should not care at all about local time zone. At most, if you want the user to be able to override the local time zone on their workstation, you can store that setting and hand it back to the client later. But the client-side code should be doing the conversion to local time (or whatever the user's picked as their "local" time zone).